# AWS amplify, fails to compile because of mock-aws-s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I´m trying to deploy my next.js app into aws Amplify but i keep getting the same error every time I try to deploy it. I was able to deploy the app twice already but when i tried to updated it the third time the console threw me this message:

```
2021-08-24T21:03:47.297Z [INFO]: Starting SSR Build...
2021-08-24T21:04:41.460Z [ERROR]: Error: Command failed with exit code 1: node_modules/.bin/next build
                                  warn  - No ESLint configuration detected. Run next lint to begin setup
                                  Failed to compile.
                                  ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mock-aws-s3' in '/codebuild/output/src724308348/src/proyect-live/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util'
                                  > Build error occurred
                                  Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
                                  at /codebuild/output/src724308348/src/proyect-live/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:924
                                  at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/codebuild/output/src724308348/src/proyect-live/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)
                                  info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
                                  info  - Checking validity of types...
                                  info  - Creating an optimized production build...
                                  at makeError (/root/.//node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:59:11)
                                  at handlePromise (/root/.//node_modules/execa/index.js:114:26)
                                  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
                                  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 1: node_modules/.bin/next build',
                                  command: 'node_modules/.bin/next build',
                                  exitCode: 1,
                                  signal: undefined,
                                  signalDescription: undefined,
                                  stdout: 'info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5\n' +
                                  'info  - Checking validity of types...\n' +
                                  'info  - Creating an optimized production build...',
                                  stderr: 'warn  - No ESLint configuration detected. Run next lint to begin setup\n' +
                                  'Failed to compile.\n' +
                                  '\n' +
                                  "ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mock-aws-s3' in '/codebuild/output/src724308348/src/proyect-live/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util'\n" +
                                  '\n' +
                                  '\n' +
                                  '> Build error occurred\n' +
                                  'Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors\n' +
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "proyect-nextjs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.7",
    "next": "^11.0.0",
    "next-auth": "^3.29.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

I saw in the message that the module mock-aws-s3 "was not found" but i never used this module anywhere and I have no idea where it is comming from.

Has anybody else had this issue or knows what might be causing the problem?